# How to modify letter-spacing in a JTextPane?

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jtextpane, letter-spacing

I'm need to modify letter-spacing (font tracking) in a JTextPane, and I can't get it to work.

When I'm using a JTextArea, I can just do:

```
Font font = new Font("Courier New", Font.PLAIN, 10);
HashMap <TextAttribute, Object> attrs = new HashMap<TextAttribute, Object>();
attrs.put(TextAttribute.TRACKING, -0.1);
font = font.deriveFont(attrs);
textArea.setFont(font);
```

but as I need to change line spacing, I need to use a JTextPane, and doing:

```
textPane.setFont(font)
```

as I did with the JTextArea doesn't work. another thing I tried was:

```
MutableAttributeSet set = new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setLineSpacing(set, -0.2);
StyleConstants.setFontFamily(set,"Courier New");
StyleConstants.setFontSize(set, 10);
set.addAttribute(TextAttribute.TRACKING, -0.1);
ta.setParagraphAttributes(set, true);
```

But the tracking attribute doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean kerning? This one shows how to specify custom kerning and some more text effect
http://java-sl.com/gp_effects.html

Comment: I tried that, and works, but it breaks the line-spacing attribute. So it's not good enough...