# Set font width in a JTextPane

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to set the font width in a JTextPane, but somehow I didn't find out how this could be done.

Here is the code I already have:

```
Font resultFont = new Font("Courier", Font.PLAIN, 12);

JTextPane resultPane = new JTextPane();
resultPane.setText(result);
resultPane.setFont(resultFont);
resultPane.setEditable(false);

add(resultPane);
```

It would be really cool, if there was any possibility to stretch the font, because I want to display some ASCII-Art.

Comment: *"any possibility to stretch the font"*  What DYM?

Comment: Why don't you use JTextArea instead, it's almost he same thing, but I doesn't support styled documents like JTextPane does. This should mean that setting font should work

Comment: As said in the answer below, I think that setting kerning would work for me... I'll try out that and if it doesn't work I'll give JTextArea a try

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you want to actually stretch the characters or only adjust the "kerning" (space between characters).
If it's just the kerning: you can find a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673281/how-to-modify-letter-spacing-in-a-jtextpane)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for monospace font: [SWT - OS agnostic way to get monospaced font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221568/swt-os-agnostic-way-to-get-monospaced-font)

And here's an example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class TestProject extends JPanel{

    public TestProject(){
        super();

       JTextPane ta = new JTextPane();

       //If you want to adjust your line spacing too
       MutableAttributeSet set = new SimpleAttributeSet();
       StyleConstants.setLineSpacing(set, -.2f);
       ta.setParagraphAttributes(set, false);

       //Making font monospaced
       ta.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 20));

       //Apply your ascii art
       ta.setText(" .-.\n(o o) boo!\n| O \\\n \\   \\\n  `~~~'");

       //Add to panel
        add(ta, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
                frame.setContentPane(new TestProject());    
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```